# How to drop by filter input logs in logstash

Tags: logging, logstash, config

I want to filter my incoming messages. 
I don`t want receive messages, which contains next regexp:

```
\*sshd\*|\*k8s_kube\-proxy\*|\*k8s_kube\-proxy\*|worker|\-proxy|k8s_influxdb|\*sshd\*|\*k8s_kube\-proxy\*|\*k8s_kube\-proxy\*|worker|\-proxy|k8s_influxdb|200\ POST|200\ GET|GET\ 200|GET\ /status\ HTTP/1\.1
```

How to write logstash config properly?

Answer (score 1):

There is an `if` construct that takes a regular expression and a `drop` filter to get rid of events.

Putting that together:

```
filter {
  if ([message] =~ /YOUR_REGEX_HERE/) {
    drop {}
  }
}
```